# Query optimisation to remove nested loop

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, t-sql, optimization, query

I have below query which is having high Sub-tree cost. I have created appropriate Indexes for for the query which are getting seek but, still the sub-tree cost in high.

however, I can see nested Loop (Inner Join) operator have 92% cost in the execution plan.

Can someone suggest any query level optimisation which will help in reducing the sub-tree cost of the query?

Query:

```
SELECT EVT_ID, ENC_ID, PROH_ID FROM  TRN_PROCEDURE_ORDER, TRN_ENCOUNTERS,TRN_EVENT_LOG 
WHERE PROH_STATUS IN ('C','R') AND ((PROH_RESULT_ENC_ID IS NULL AND PROH_ENC_ID = ENC_ID) 
OR PROH_RESULT_ENC_ID = ENC_ID) AND ENC_BOOL_DELETED = 0 
AND EVT_ENC_ID = ENC_ID AND EVT_TYPE = 2 AND EVT_BOOL_ACTION2 = 0 
AND ENC_APPT_LOCATION='AS' AND EVT_TIMESTAMP >  '2022-04-08 02:19:03'  
ORDER BY ENC_ID DESC,PROH_ID DESC
```

This is the equivalent query with aliases and ANSI-92 style joins:

```
SELECT C.EVT_ID, A.ENC_ID, PROH_ID 
FROM TRN_ENCOUNTERS A 
INNER JOIN TRN_PROCEDURE_ORDER B ON 
    ((B.PROH_RESULT_ENC_ID IS NULL AND B.PROH_ENC_ID = A.ENC_ID) 
    OR B.PROH_RESULT_ENC_ID = A.ENC_ID) 
INNER JOIN TRN_EVENT_LOG C ON C.EVT_ENC_ID = A.ENC_ID 
WHERE 
    B.PROH_STATUS IN ('C','R') 
    AND A.ENC_BOOL_DELETED = 0 
    AND C.EVT_ENC_ID = ENC_ID 
    AND C.EVT_TYPE = 2 
    AND C.EVT_BOOL_ACTION2 = 0 
    AND A.ENC_APPT_LOCATION='AS' 
    AND C.EVT_TIMESTAMP > '2022-04-07 02:19:03'
```

Also, find actual execution plan in below URL for your reference
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rydro3uAq

Thank you.

Comment: it may not be the nested loop you want to focus on in the plan (which had 0 actual rows) rather the preceding spool which was estimated at ~86000 rows but read ~43 million rows.

Comment: For query performance questions, we need to see the full table *and index* schemas of the relevant tables. Adding table aliases and referencing those aliases on each column, as well as using explicit join syntax rather than the old comma-joins, would help immensely in understanding your query.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, the loop join itself is not likely the issue, rather it's the giant table spool, which is expecting a small amount of distinct rows. A lazy table spool is usually an indication of poor indexing.

Firstly, rewrite your query to use explicit joins, and use table aliases everywhere, and use `ISNULL` rather than that `OR`.

I've had to guess which columns are on which table, and this answer is based on that.

```sql
SELECT
  evt.EVT_ID,
  enc.ENC_ID,
  proh.PROH_ID
FROM
  TRN_PROCEDURE_ORDER proh
  JOIN TRN_ENCOUNTERS enc ON ISNULL(proh.PROH_RESULT_ENC_ID, proh.PROH_ENC_ID) = enc.ENC_ID
  JOIN TRN_EVENT_LOG evt ON evt.EVT_ENC_ID = enc.ENC_ID
WHERE proh.PROH_STATUS IN ('C', 'R')
  AND enc.ENC_BOOL_DELETED = 0 
  AND evt.EVT_TYPE = 2
  AND evt.EVT_BOOL_ACTION2 = 0 
  AND enc.ENC_APPT_LOCATION = 'AS'
  AND evt.EVT_TIMESTAMP >  '2022-04-08 02:19:03'  
ORDER BY
  enc.ENC_ID DESC,
  proh.PROH_ID DESC;
```

To make this performant, you are first going to need a computed column for the `ISNULL`

```sql
ALTER TABLE TRN_PROCEDURE_ORDER
  ADD Final_ENC_ID AS ISNULL(PROH_RESULT_ENC_ID, PROH_ENC_ID)
```

Then you need the following filtered indexes

```sql
CREATE INDEX IX ON TRN_PROCEDURE_ORDER (
  Final_ENC_ID,
  PROH_ID
)
WHERE (
  PROH_STATUS IN ('C', 'R')
)
```

```sql
CREATE INDEX IX ON TRN_ENCOUNTERS (
  ENC_ID
)
WHERE (
  ENC_BOOL_DELETED = 0
  AND ENC_APPT_LOCATION = 'AS'
)
```

```sql
CREATE INDEX IX ON TRN_EVENT_LOG (
  EVT_TIMESTAMP,
  EVT_ENC_ID
)
WHERE (
  EVT_TYPE = 2
  AND EVT_BOOL_ACTION2 = 0
)
```

At this point, I would imagine a merge join or an *indexed* nested loop may be the best. Please share the latest query plan.

An alternative to the computed column is to use a `UNION ALL` instead of the `OR`, and then have separate filtered indexes `WHERE PROH_RESULT_ENC_ID IS NULL` and `WHERE PROH_RESULT_ENC_ID IS NOT NULL`.